# Add a "Leave open" button to questions that have close votes

Tags: feature-request

New questions often fall victim to posted-too-early issues, consequently they quickly attract close votes. This is as it should be, but when the problem is remedied it would be convenient if it were possible to vote to leave open directly from the question.

Comment: What is a `posted-too-early` issue?

Comment: @Matt, slugster: yes these are very close to this question, I missed them in my pre-search. It seems this has not been implemented though?

Comment: @Thor If you read Shog9's answer, he clearly mentions that keeping the *Leave Open* in the review queue was by design.

Comment: @Mike: I often see people posting questions, only to make major edits soon after.

Comment: Maybe those people should make those edits before posting their questions then. If you post an incomplete question, why wonder if it's going to be closed soon?

Comment: @slhck: Thanks for pointing me to Shog9's answer. The provisions mentioned (flagging, commenting) seem reasonable to me. I think I missed the original discussion because I was unaware that "Do not close" has been renamed to "Leave open".